# Accelerometer sensitivity range

Tags: sensor, accelerometer

I'm looking at the [KX023](http://kionixfs.kionix.com/en/datasheet/KX023-1025%20Specifications%20Rev%2011.0.pdf) and it seems to have a 64 counts/g sensitivity.

Its datasheet specifies the following

[image]

What I don't quite understand is why there're two sets of figures. The top set goes up to 16k counts/g whilst the bottom goes up to 64 counts/g. 64c/g would seem very low when others like [MMA8452](http://www.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/data_sheet/MMA8452Q.pdf) supports 1024 c/g.

How come "Buffet 8-bit mode" gives so much lower sensitivity?

Thanks

Comment: Because in 8 bit mode you throw away the 8 LSBs. So you get 1/256 as many counts.

Comment: I have added more information in my answer to better reflect your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page 54:

> BRES determines the resolution of the acceleration data samples collected by the sample 
>   buffer.
>   BUF_RES = 0
>
> 8-bit samples are accumulated in the buffer
>
> BUF_RES = 1
>
> 16-bit samples are accumulated in the buffer

Page 7:

> Current consumption: High resolution mode 145 uA typical, Low power mode 10 uA typical.
>   Bandwidth: High resolution mode ODR/2, Low power mode 800 Hz.

On page 8 there are also diagrams which shows how the start up time and representative current. This is very much affected by the ODR (Output Data Rate). Higher output data rate gives a higher current consumption and longer start up time.

The ODR is set by register ODCNTL bit0 to bit3, seen in Table 21, page 43. This table also shows which data rates are available for low power mode. Note that the Directional Tap feature data rate is handled by another register.

Comment: Sure. But it it's capable of handling 16k counts/g, why does it offer an 8 bit mode? Higher sensitivity should be always better, right?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the samples are recorded using 16 bits per sample.  Eight-bit mode, of course, uses only eight bits.

With eight bits, you can represent \$256\$ values.

Let's look at 8-bit mode, \$\pm 2g\$. This gives a full range from \$-2g\$ to \$+2g\$, which is \$4g\$ total.  \$256\$ values divided by \$4g\$ = \$64\$ values per \$g\$. This is what is listed on the datasheet.

Similarly, 16-bit samples will allow \$65,536\$ values.  Divide this by the same \$4g\$ range and you get \$16,384\$ values per \$g\$.

The reason that both are offered is so that the designer can choose between greater accuracy or reduced data overhead.  One example where 8-bit mode might be used is if the product is simply going to log how often it is moved. It wouldn't need any great accuracy, and you could store twice as many samples.

Comment: I don't quite understand why an 8 bit mode is even offered. Isn't higher resolution always better?

Comment: @Kar Almost always :) A few examples might be: 1. Detecting _if_ something moved vs _how_ it moved. 2. Logging data for a long time with limited available memory. 3. Extending battery life. I'm not sure about this IC, but some consume less power when only doing rough measurements.

Comment: Accelerometers can be so low-powered that the SPI transaction  uses more current than the measurement itself.  So cutting the transaction in half (by transmitting 8 bits instead of 16) is a significant power savings.  Also, those low bits contain random acceleration noise if the device can be used in a car or handheld.  So nothing of value is lost when discarding them.

Comment: I see. Is SPI meant to use more power than I2C?